# If an operator has a discrete spectrum eigenvalues, but infinitely many eigenvalues, are these necessarily countable?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, spectral-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, eigenfunctions

And are the eigenfunctions countable?

This question was motivated thinking about operators in quantum mechanics, which are Hermitian, however I would be interested in knowing about operators in general.

Some of the operators I have come across in Quantum mechanics which have infinitely many eigenvalues are the position and momentum operators (generally uncountably infintely many eigenvalues and eigenstates), the Hamiltonian which can have uncountably infinite energy spectrum for an unbound particle, or countably infinite for a bound particle. It seems that the operators which have discrete eigenvalues necessarily have countable ones. I was wondering if this is a general result.

Comment: The points of the continuous spectrum corresponding to unbound particles are not eigenvalues because their eigenfunctions are not square integrable. The Hilbert space has a countable basis. (I assume you are talking about a Schrodinger Hamiltonian.)

Answer (score 1):

A discrete subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is countable (either finite or infinite), yes. As for the eigenfunctions, technically you could have discrete spectrum and still have uncountably many linearly independent eigenfunctions, just consider the zero operator on a space of large enough dimension. But this is a rather pathological case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is there a proof of duscrete subsets of C being countable? I presume from the phrasing that discrete subsets of any guven continuous set are not necessarily countable?

Comment: @21joanna12 It comes from the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is $\sigma$-compact (it can be written as a countable union of compact subsets). So if you had an uncountable subset of $\mathbb{C}$, uncountably many elements would need to lie in some compact subset, and then the set couldn't be discrete.